# mysql missing field after running rails db migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

i have a rails migration:

```
>> cat db/migrate/20091126031039_create_cards.rb 
class CreateCards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :cards do |t|
      t.string :number_hash
      t.int :number
      t.string :name
      t.string :type
      t.string :expiration
      t.int :sec_code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :cards
  end
end
```

notice the "t.int :sec_code" line.  it seems to execute successfully:

```
>> rake db:migrate(in /Users/aaronj1335/Sites/clarkbox)
==  CreateCards: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:cards)
   -> 0.4315s
==  CreateCards: migrated (0.4317s) ===========================================
```

but the "sec_code" column isn't created:

```
mysql> describe cards;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| number_hash | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| type        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| expiration  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

why isn't the sec_code column created?  it seems like i should get an error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t.int should probably be t.integer. Give that a shot.

When in doubt, [dizzy](http://dizzy.co.uk/) always has some great references.

Answer (score 0):

Well I also dont see the "number" field being created properly, so it must be the type (t.int :number is missing)